# how can I get top terms info from apache solr  via Java API

Tags: java, solr, client

I know  http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/schema.jsp can provide me the top terms for any given field, while how can I get them from Java API(Java client)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SolrJ Java client for Solr:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

and more precisely, look at:

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;

Answer (score 1):

You can use LukeRequestHandler to get the top terms:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler